# accessing members of members of a union in C

Tags: c, struct, enums

I'm a bit new to C and I'm trying to access some members ofa struct that is inside of a union that is inside of a struct. I have tried something like `struct.struct.member` but it was a fail I also tried to access it using the arrow operator(replacing the '.' with '->') but it did not work as well.
so in my case I was trying to access the "program", that is inside of the "tree_node" struct. this is the code of the struct:

```
struct tree_node;
typedef struct tree_node node_t;

struct tree_node
{
    enum node_type type;

    union {
        struct {
            char *program;
            char **argv;
            size_t argc;
        } command;

        struct {
            node_t **parts; // array
            size_t n_parts;
        } pipe;

        struct {
            node_t *child;
            int fd; // >= 0 specific fd; -1 stdout+stderr
            enum redirect_type mode;
            union {
                int fd2;
                char *target;
            };
        } redirect;

        struct {
            node_t *child;
        } subshell;

        struct {
            node_t *child;
        } detach;

        struct {
            node_t *first;
            node_t *second;
        } sequence;
    };
};
```

the code (that doesn't word) that I'm using to access "program" currently is this:

```
node_t *n

if (n.command.program == "cd")
        {
            printf("cd command entered\n");
        }
```

any idea where am i going wrong?
Cheers :)

Comment: You are comparing addresses of strings, not their contents.

Comment: Seems like all you need is `0 == strcmp("cd",n->command.program)` in your if statement

Comment: "I also tried to access it using the arrow operator(replacing the '.' with '->')" Which of the two did you replace? Only the first one must be replaced: `n` is a pointer, so `n->` is correct.

Comment: You also need a semicolon after `node_t *n`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an example how to access those structures/unions by the object or pointer. Take a look on the last example. It shows how to use anonymous structures/unions - they only have to have didstinct fields names

```
void foo()
{
    node_t obj, *ptr;

    ptr -> pipe.n_parts = 5;
    printf("%s\n", ptr -> command.program);

    obj.detach.child = ptr;
    obj.bar = obj.foo;
}
```

data structure is here

```
struct tree_node;
typedef struct tree_node node_t;

struct tree_node
{
    int type;

    union {
        struct {
            char *program;
            char **argv;
            size_t argc;
        } command;

        struct {
            node_t **parts; // array
            size_t n_parts;
        } pipe;

        struct {
            node_t *child;
            int fd; // >= 0 specific fd; -1 stdout+stderr
            int mode;
            union {
                int fd2;
                char *target;
            };
        } redirect;

        struct {
            node_t *child;
        } subshell;

        struct {
            node_t *child;
        } detach;

        struct {
            node_t *first;
            node_t *second;
        } sequence;

        struct {
            node_t *bar;
            node_t *foo;
        };

    };
};
```